# Updating DataGridView via ComboBox Selection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` (called `SummaryDataGrid`) in a Windows Form Class (called `SummaryForm`) that I am trying to update programmatically via a `ComboBox` drop-down selection (called YearComboBox). `SummaryDataGrid` is not editable by the user, and it is simply used to display information in a spreadsheet-like manner. I want to be able to use `YearComboBox` for the user to select the year and then for `SummaryDataGrid` to update its values based on that year selection. You can see a screencap of the `SummaryForm` at the link below, showing `SummaryDataGrid` populated by the year 2020.

[SummaryForm view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie03i.png)

`YearComboBox` is not data-bound, and neither is `SummaryDataGrid`. To populate `SummaryDataGrid` programmatically, I do so by creating `DataGridViewRows` in `SummaryForm` and then populate the data by pulling from my SQL Database using functions defined in my `MainForm`, which in turn use functions defined in my Dataset that is linked to my `SQL Server` that I host. Some code examples can be found below.

```
public partial class SummaryForm : Form
{
    private DataGridViewRow JanuaryRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow FebruaryRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow MarchRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow AprilRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow MayRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow JuneRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow JulyRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow AugustRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow SeptemberRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow OctoberRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow NovemberRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow DecemberRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow TotalRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    private DataGridViewRow AverageRow = new DataGridViewRow();

    private int year = DateTime.Today.Year;
    ...
    // form load event handler
    private void SummaryForm_FormLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        YearComboBox.Text = year.ToString();

        JanuaryRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        FebruaryRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        MarchRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        AprilRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        MayRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        JuneRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        JulyRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        AugustRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        SeptemberRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        OctoberRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        NovemberRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        DecemberRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        TotalRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);
        AverageRow.CreateCells(SummaryDataGrid);

        // populate january row
        JanuaryRow.Cells[0].Value = "January";
        JanuaryRow.Cells[1].Value = MainFormInstance.BillsOfSaleCountMonth(1, year);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[2].Value = MainFormInstance.BillsOfSaleCashMonth(1, year);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[3].Value = MainFormInstance.BillsOfSaleCreditMonth(1, year);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[2].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[3].Value);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[5].Value = MainFormInstance.CashMonth(1, year);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[6].Value = MainFormInstance.CardMonth(1, year);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[7].Value = MainFormInstance.MonthCP(1, year);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[8].Value = MainFormInstance.ExpensesMonthCP(1, year) + MainFormInstance.BillsOfSaleCashMonth(1, year);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[9].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[7].Value) - Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[8].Value);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[10].Value = MainFormInstance.MonthCF(1, year);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[11].Value = MainFormInstance.ExpensesMonthCF(1, year);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[12].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[10].Value) - Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[11].Value);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[13].Value = MainFormInstance.ExpensesMonthGeneral(1, year);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[14].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[5].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[6].Value);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[15].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[8].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[11].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[13].Value);
        JanuaryRow.Cells[16].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[14].Value) - Convert.ToDecimal(JanuaryRow.Cells[15].Value);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows.Add(JanuaryRow);
        ...
    }

    // year combo box selection event handler
    private void SummaryForm_YearChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        year = int.Parse(YearComboBox.Text);
        PopulateSummaryDataGrid();
    }

    // populate the summary data grid
    private void PopulateSummaryDataGrid()
    {
        // stubbed
    }
```

I have defined a SelectedValueChanged Event Handler for `YearComboBox`, and initially tried moving the populating of each row into a separate function from the `FormLoad` event handler. The idea was for the `FormLoad` event handler to update the YearComboBox initial Text attribute from the year variable defined in SummaryForm, perform the `CreateCells()` calls for each row, and then call a separate void function to perform the populating. However, when debugging, the separate function would immediately reach the first JanuaryRow statement trying to edit the cell and would say that the index was -1 and therefore out of range. I tried just having the SelectedValueChanged event trigger the `FormLoad` event handler, but that didn't work either due to the row already being created and populated.

So, my question is how can I just get this drop-down selection to change the year used by the statements in the `FormLoad` event handler (which works fine) and have it repopulate the DataGridView with the new values based on the updated year?

Comment: Have you tried the clear your datagriview
SummaryDataGrid.Rows.Clear();
SummaryDataGrid.Refresh();
also you can extract the codes which add rows to datagridview to a method instead of doing it on from load

Comment: I am glad you found a solution, but I have to ask, is there some reason you want the code to re-gather the data every time the user changes the year? It is unknown how many years are in the combo box, but gathering all the data years ONCE and storing them into a container like a `DataSet` or `List<T>` seems like a better approach. Manually adding columns and rows to the grid with each change in the combo box just seems redundant when you could return a container by using your current code… instead of wring to the grid, write to a `DataTable` and save it… just a suggestion. Good Luck.

Comment: @JohnG There are only two years in the program, 2020 and 2021. 2021 does not actually have any data yet. The data is stored in a DataSet that interfaces with an SQL Server I have setup that stores all of the information. Switching between years is a fairly rare occurrence for the user, typically they just want to load the current year which loads in the FormLoad event handler. Occasionally, the user may want to swap back to a previous year just to look at growth or seasonal trends. As the sole user of this program, it works as needed in this way.

Comment: @JohnG Also, to be clear, the rows are only created and added once in the FormLoad event handler. In the answer to my question that I posted, I found out how to simply edit the DataGridView cells directly in a separate method that is called by the combo box event handler and this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I seem to have stumbled upon a solution while trying different things out. May not be the most elegant, but here's what my implementation of PopulateSummaryGrid() in case anyone else runs into this issue:

```
// populate the summary data grid
    private void PopulateSummaryDataGrid()
    {
        // update January row
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = MainFormInstance.BillsOfSaleCountMonth(1, year);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = MainFormInstance.BillsOfSaleCashMonth(1, year);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = MainFormInstance.BillsOfSaleCreditMonth(1, year);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value = MainFormInstance.CashMonth(1, year);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[6].Value = MainFormInstance.CardMonth(1, year);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[7].Value = MainFormInstance.MonthCP(1, year);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[8].Value = MainFormInstance.ExpensesMonthCP(1, year) + MainFormInstance.BillsOfSaleCashMonth(1, year);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[9].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[7].Value) - Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[8].Value);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[10].Value = MainFormInstance.MonthCF(1, year);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[11].Value = MainFormInstance.ExpensesMonthCF(1, year);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[12].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[10].Value) - Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[11].Value);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[13].Value = MainFormInstance.ExpensesMonthGeneral(1, year);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[14].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[6].Value);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[15].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[8].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[11].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[13].Value);
        SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[16].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[14].Value) - Convert.ToDecimal(SummaryDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[15].Value);
        ...
        SummaryDataGrid.Refresh();
    }
```

I also had to remove the first statement of my FormLoad event handler that set the text of YearComboBox to the current year. This seems to have everything working properly.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.